# React - Tooltip Return New Line Using String Concatenation

Tags: javascript, tooltip, styled-components, string-concatenation, carriage-return

I'm trying to figure out how I can make a Tooltip title appear on multiple lines using the correct string concatenation.

**This is what it looks like now:**

```
First Name: John Last Name: Doe
```

**This is what I'm trying for the Tooltip:**

```
First Name: John
Last Name: Doe
```

I'm using Material UI/Styled Components.

I've already tried styling the Tooltip with 'whitespace' and multiline={true} and tried `&#13;&#10;` and '\n' but it did not work. I think it's a particular case so I'm not sure on how to do this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!  Thank you

```js
<StyledToolbar>
        <StyledButtonsContainer>
                <IconButton>
                    <Tooltip title={`First Name: ${firstname}` + '\n' + `Last Name:${lastname} `}>
                        <AccountCircleIcon />
                    </Tooltip>
                </IconButton>
        </StyledButtonsContainer>
</StyledToolbar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Tooltip title={<>First Name: {firstname}<br/>Last Name: {lastname}</>}>
  <AccountCircleIcon />
</Tooltip>
```

Comment: I did get an error about the format: "Missing parentheses around multilines JSX "
The solution is to add parentheses before <> and after </>